# Understanding last-child

Tags: css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have the following html structure:

```
<div class="decorator">
    <div class="EC_MyICHP_Item">
        <div class="text">
            <h3><a target="_blank" title="" href="#"></a></h3>
            text here text here text here text here text here text here 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="EC_MyICHP_Item">
        <div class="text">
            <h3><a target="_blank" title="" href="#"></a></h3>
            text here text here text here text here text here text here 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="EC_MyICHP_Item">
        <div class="text">
            <h3><a target="_blank" title="" href="#"></a></h3>
            text here text here text here text here text here text here 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="readmore"><a></a></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to select the LAST EC_MyICHP_Item, by using last-child, but in vain. (both CSS and jQuery) Could you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: I did a mistake in my code: There is a last div that I just added. I believe this is interfering, although it doesn't have the same class name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `:last-child` at the end of the selector.

`div.EC_MyICHP_Item:last-child`

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-lastchild

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/zrufd/

Please note: this will not work in earlier versions of IE.

**EDIT**

As per the comment about the last `div` being added and it interfering.  You're right.  It does cause `:last-child` to choke... at least in Chrome where I tested it.

If your HTML structure remains the same, that is, always three `div.EC_MyICHP_Item`, you could do this

`.EC_MyICHP_Item:nth-child(3)`

**Updated Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/zrufd/1/

**EDIT #2**

> unfortunately the number of EC_MyICHP_Item div's varies

In that case, I would use jQuery:

```
$('.EC_MyICHP_Item:last')
```

**Further updated example:** http://jsfiddle.net/zrufd/2/

Comment: I did a mistake in my code: There is a last div that I just added. I believe this is interfering, although it doesn't have the same class name.

Comment: unfortunately the number of EC_MyICHP_Item div's varies :/

Comment: Alright @George. I think jQuery is the only option now.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

`.EC_MyICHP_Item:last-child` should work well.

It's important to realize that `E:last-child` means "an E element, which is a last child", not "last child of E element".

Answer (score 0):

I added the ID for merely testing purposes.

But use `:last`.

http://jsfiddle.net/aDbcW/1/

Answer (score 0):

`.EC_MyICHP_Item:last-child` would only work if the div is the last child of its parent div. Since you have `div.readmore` as the last child of the parent, your selector wouldn't work. You need to use `.EC_MyICHP_Item:last-of-type` instead.

Edit: in jQuery this would translate to `.EC_MyICHP_Item:last`.

Comment: the last-of-type selector did not work (tested in fiddle) I'll try jQuery for cross-browser support